# Is it possible to reinterpret pointer as dimensioned array reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Suppose I have some pointer, which I want to reinterpret as static dimension array reference:

```
double *p;
double (&r)[4] = ?(p); // some construct?

// clarify
template< size_t N> void function(double (&a)[N]);
...
 double *p;
function(p); // this will not work.
//  I would like to cast p as to make it appear as  double[N]
```

Is it possible to do so?
how do I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's ugly:

```
double arr[4];
double* d = arr;

double (&a)[4] = *static_cast<double(*)[4]>(static_cast<void*>(d));
```

Be sure the array type matches what the pointer originally came from.

Comment: `double(*)[4]`, what is this construct?  this is the first time I see it

Comment: one last question, why cast to void* first?

Comment: @aaa: We could do: `reinterpret_cast<double(*)[4]>(d)`, but this relies on implementation defined behavior. C++ standard guarantees that a cast from `void*` to `T*` will always work as long as the `void*` originally pointed at that `T`. The code above is well-formed, because `d`, when casted to `void*`, does indeed point to the original type we are casting to. (This is also why I warn the cast matches exactly what the pointer points at. If we were to cast to anything else, we'd have undefined behavior.)

Comment: what if d was `new double[]` originally, rather than pointer to double[4]?  would `a` still be valid (in first four elements)?  I was not quite clear if by type T you meant double or `double[4]`.
thank you

Comment: By `T` I meant `double[4]`. I *think* that should work because `double` is a POD type. Hopefully someone else can chime in to confirm.

Comment: I was always of the impression that `reinterpret_cast<T&>(p)` would be the same as `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)`, but I wanted to comment that since reinterpret_cast is implementation defined this isn't always true. This is a good example because compiling on my system with GCC 4.7, the cast to reference is giving an address 8 bytes offset from the dereferenced cast to pointer. The cast to pointer, cast to type, dereference route is more verbose but definitely safer.

Comment: @GManNickG, This is **not** OK.  The second line `double* d = arr;` is array to pointer implicit conversion the result of which is "a pointer to the first element of the array." See [conv.array]. But `double*` and `double (*) [4]` are different pointer types, and these pointer types are not _pointer-interconvertable_ see [basic.compound] [C++17 6.9.2.4] Therefore what you have is the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast<double(*)[4]>(d)` and this violates the _strict aliasing rule_.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it's called a `vector` :)

```
std::vector<double> myVariableArray(4)
```

---

EDIT: Rereading, it looks like you want to get the size an array was declared with. You can't do that -- that's a template method feature you can use on occasion. Since a `double *` doesn't even need to point to `double`s there's little way a compiler could give you a sensible answer in any case.

Comment: @GMan: Yeah -- just realized that. Edited. Initially interpreted that as "Can I create an array with a dimension known at runtime"

Answer (score -4):

```
double *array;
...
...
int sizearray = sizeof(array)/sizeof(double);
```

Comment: The logic here is wrong. `array` carries no information about what it points to. This will always return the same answer, no matter what.

Comment: sizeof(array) when array is a pointer will give back the pointer size, usually 4 or more depending on OS.