# Is it legal to cast a pointer to array reference using static_cast in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, type-safety, static-cast

I have a pointer `T * pValues` that I would like to view as a `T (&values)[N]`

In this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634994/239916, the proposed way of doing this is

```
T (&values)[N] = *static_cast<T(*)[N]>(static_cast<void*>(pValues));
```

The concern I have about this is. In his example, `pValues` is initialized in the following way

```
T theValues[N];
T * pValues = theValues;
```

My question is whether the cast construct is legal if `pValues` comes from any of the following constructs:

#### 1:

```
T theValues[N + M]; // M > 0
T * pValues = theValues;
```

#### 2:

```
T * pValues = new T[N + M]; // M >= 0
```

Comment: `*static_cast<T(*)[N]>(static_cast<void*>(pValues))` seems to be abusing of language's features and rather an ugly workaround than something you would actually want to use...

Comment: Your memory in both 1 and 2 would be dynamic - that is, the pointer is an actual pointer to the starting point of a block of memory, not an array that has been decayed to a pointer.  Seems like it would be UB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: You are right. The cast is safe only if `pValues` is of type `T[N]` and both of the cases you mention (different size, dynamically allocated array) will most likely lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

The nice thing about `static_cast` is that some additional checks are made in compile time so if it seems that you are doing something wrong, compiler will complain about it (compared to ugly C-style cast that allows you to do almost anything), e.g.:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct C { double d; };

int main() {
    A a;
    // C* c = (C*) &a; // possible to compile, but leads to undefined behavior
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(&a);
}
```

will give you: `invalid static_cast from type ‘A*’ to type ‘C*’`

In this case you cast to `void*`, which from the view of checks that can be made in compile time is legal for almost anything, and vice versa: `void*` can be cast back to almost anything as well, which makes the usage of `static_cast` completely useless at first place since these checks become useless.

For the previous example:

```
C* c = static_cast<C*>(static_cast<void*>(&a));
```

is no better than:

```
C* c = (C*) &a;
```

and will most likely lead to incorrect usage of this pointer and ***undefined behavior*** with it.

---

In other words:

```
A arr[N];
A (&ref)[N] = *static_cast<A(*)[N]>(&arr);
```

is safe and just fine. But once you start abusing `static_cast<void*>` there are no guarantees at all about what will actually happen because even stuff like:

```
C *pC = new C;
A (&ref2)[N] = *static_cast<A(*)[N]>(static_cast<void*>(&pC));
```

becomes possible.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't exactly answer my question as you are introducing two types (A and C), whereas I'm asking about the case where there is one (non-pointer non-reference) type T being involved.

Comment: IMHO static cast to void* should have been illegal by standard.

Comment: `A (&ref)[N] = *static_cast<A(*)[N]>(&arr);`: The static_cast doesn't do anything. `&arr` already has that type.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 at least the shown expression isn't safe, even if `pValues` is a pointer to the first element of the array and the array is of exactly matching type (including excat size), whether obtained from a variable declaration or a call to `new`. (If theses criteria are not satisfied it is UB regardless of the following.)

Arrays and their first element are not *pointer-interconvertible* and therefore `reinterpret_cast` (which is equivalent to two `static_casts` through `void*`) cannot cast the pointer value of one to a pointer value of the other.

Consequently `static_cast<T(*)[N]>(static_cast<void*>(pValues))` will still point at the first element of the array, not the array object itself.

Derferencing this pointer is then undefined behavior, because of the type/value mismatch.

This can be potentially remedied with `std::launder`, which may change the pointer value where `reinterpret_cast` can't. Specifically the following may be well-defined:

```
T (&values)[N] = *std::launder(static_cast<T(*)[N]>(static_cast<void*>(pValues)));
```

or equivalently

```
T (&values)[N] = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T(*)[N]>(pValues));
```

but only if the pointer that would be returned by `std::launder` cannot be used to access any bytes that weren't accessible through the original `pValues` pointer. This is satified if the array is a complete object, but e.g. not satisfied if the array is a subarray of a two-dimensional array.

For the exact reachability condition, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder.