# Creating sub-array reference via cast?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I want to call a function whose signature looks like this:

```
void foo(int (&ra)[2]);
```

That is, its argument is a reference to an array of two elements. Let's suppose the author of that function (who shall remain nameless) is not inclined to change the interface.

I want to invoke the function on a sub-array of an existing array. Like this:

```
void bar()
{
  int vals[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  foo(reinterpret_cast<int (&)[2]>(vals[1]));
}
```

GCC accepts this code and compiles it to what I want, but I am not at all sure this is guaranteed by the language.

Is the behavior of this code implementation-defined (or undefined)? If so, is there a way to rewrite `bar()` to do the same thing in a well-defined way?

I am more likely to accept your answer if you cite chapter and verse of the C++03 or C++11 standard.

Comment: Something tells me I've seen this before and it was valid, but don't quote me on it.

Comment: shouldn't you have `&vals[1]` instead of `vals[1]`?

Comment: @bolov, It's a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: in principle a compiler can add range checking and such. the formal UB mainly allows such things. in practice you'll be OK.

Comment: @bolov: No; `&vals[1]` is a pointer. I am casting to a reference to an array. (I could also write this by casting `&vals[1]` to a pointer to an array and then dereferencing that. I have no idea whether that would be better-defined.)

Comment: @chris Maybe [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21317140/420683)? The answers should also be relevant to this question.

Comment: @dyp, It was before 2014, but thanks.

Comment: I thought you were deleting all your content, leaving and never coming back?

Comment: How about `foo(*reinterpret_cast<int (*)[2]>(&vals[1]));`?

Comment: Ohh for $Deity's sake, forget about C-style arrays (and casts) already. Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` and everything will be much easier (and just as efficient). Why are people still learning C++ like it's 1998? It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear. C++11 [dcl.ref]/5 says

> [...] A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object
> or function.

But what is a "valid" object? Certainly there is not an object of type `int[2]` at that memory location. But then again, it's widely accepted that references are allowed to bind to allocated memory into which an object of the appropriate type will later be constructed, assuming that the construction itself has well-defined behaviour. (Actually, although C++11 doesn't do this, later versions of the standard library specification use an exposition-only function called *voidify* in order to define `std::uninitialized_copy`, which will bind a reference to the uninitialized memory location before placement new is called. So basically, the library specification relies on the fact that binding a reference is allowed in at least some cases even when there isn't a live object present.)

This is the topic of [CWG 453](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/453.html) and this issue is so old, and hasn't been discussed by CWG for such a long time, that it's anyone's guess how it will eventually get resolved (if ever), other than that the final resolution would probably get DRed back to C++98 (which can be interpreted as retroactively fixing older standards).

Once `foo`'s parameter is initialized, another question arises of what is permitted to be done with it. For example, is this valid?

```
int x = ra[1];
```

The first step in evaluating this expression is the array-to-pointer conversion, which is described at [conv.array]:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type "array of `N` `T`" or "array of unknown bound of `T`" can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to `T`". The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

But there's no actual array of size 2 that `ra` refers to, so the first element of that hypothetical array is also hypothetical. So this would seem to give UB. But then again, who knows?

Let's also take a look at C++20, keeping in mind that C++17 changed the rules around pointers so that pointers point to objects, not to addresses. (Though they "represent" addresses.) The `reinterpret_cast` is governed by [expr.reinterpret.cast]/11:

> A glvalue expression of type `T1`, designating an object *x*, can be cast to the type "reference to `T2`" if an expression of type "pointer to `T1`" can be explicitly converted to the type "pointer to `T2`" using a `reinterpret_cast`. The result is that of `*reinterpret_cast<T2 *>(p)` where `p` is a pointer to *x* of type "pointer to `T1`". [...]

So first a pointer to `vals[1]` is taken, then that pointer is `reinterpret_cast`ed to `int (*)[2]`. Under [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7, this first does a `static_cast` to `void*`, then a second `static_cast` to `int (*)[2]`. The first `static_cast` just does an implicit conversion, and under [conv.ptr]/2, an implicit conversion to *cv* `void*` leaves the value unchanged: that is, the result still points to the `int` object at `vals[1]`. The second `static_cast`, a static cast *from* `void*`, is governed by [expr.static.cast]/13, according to which

> A prvalue of type "pointer to *cv1* `void`" can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv2* `T`", where `T` is
> an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. If the original
> pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` does not satisfy the alignment requirement of `T`, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an
> object *a*, and there is an object *b* of type `T` (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (6.8.3) with *a*, the result is a pointer to *b*. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

There's no object of type `T` (which is `int[2]`) at the memory location that the `void*` represents (not points to) so its value (*i.e.* what it points to) is left unchanged; the result of the second `static_cast` is still a pointer to the `int` object at `vals[1]`, but it has type `int (*)[2]`. That might seem a bit bizarre, but that's just how it is. As the last step in evaluating the `reinterpret_cast`, this pointer is dereferenced. Under [expr.unary.op]/1, this gives an lvalue that refers to whatever object the pointer operand points to. So the final result of the `reinterpret_cast` is an lvalue of type `int[2]` that refers to a single `int` object (`vals[1]`).

Is it valid to use that lvalue to initialize `ra`? Maybe; maybe not. It would result in `ra` being initialized to refer to an object that is alive... but it doesn't have the right type for `ra`. There probably should be a rule that makes that UB. But there isn't.

And what happens if you get as far as the array-to-pointer conversion? [conv.array]/1 says:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type "array of `N` `T`" or "array of unknown bound of `T`" can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to `T`". The temporary materialization conversion (7.3.5) is applied. The result is a pointer to
> the first element of the array.

What array? `ra` doesn't even refer to an array; it refers to the `int` object at `vals[1]`. So again, I guess this is UB? But the moral of the story is that the standard is very underspecified in this area.