# constant array using programming C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
const int new_WEIGHT[GENE] = { temp_WEIGHT[0],temp_WEIGHT[1],temp_WEIGHT[2],temp_WEIGHT[3],temp_WEIGHT[4],temp_WEIGHT[5],temp_WEIGHT[6],temp_WEIGHT[7] };
```

Is there another way, rather than copying all of the array indexes? I mean, somehow another way to copy the array to another constant array? Please help!

Comment: Use a `std::array`.  They allow you to make copies of the entire array.

Comment: not very clear about what you mean. Any references?

Comment: There is documentation and some example code here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: I don't see too much point to two constant copies of the same array, They will start the same and because they are constant, they can't be changed. Might as well just use the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy a `std::array`:

```
const std::array temp_WEIGHT {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
const auto new_WEIGHT = temp_WEIGHT;
```

You can convert (and copy) a C array to a C++ array with [to_array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array):

```
const int temp_WEIGHT[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
const auto new_WEIGHT = std::to_array(temp_WEIGHT);
```

You can access the underlying array with [std::array<T,N>::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) and the size with [std::array<T,N>::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void f(int arr[], std::size_t size) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] *= 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    const int temp_WEIGHT[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    auto new_WEIGHT = std::to_array(temp_WEIGHT);
    f(new_WEIGHT.data(), new_WEIGHT.size());
    for (const auto &el : new_WEIGHT) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

If you need a reference to a C array you can

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t SIZE>
void f(int (&arr)[SIZE]) {
    for (auto &el : arr) {
        el *= 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    const int temp_WEIGHT[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    auto new_WEIGHT = std::to_array(temp_WEIGHT);
    f(*static_cast<int(*)[new_WEIGHT.size()]>(static_cast<void*>(new_WEIGHT.data())));
    for (const auto &el : new_WEIGHT) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

From [Is it legal to cast a pointer to array reference using static_cast in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317140/is-it-legal-to-cast-a-pointer-to-array-reference-using-static-cast-in-c) I understand that this is well-defined and legal.

That said I don't see any reason to use C arrays today.